# Consistency Rules for cudaHostAllocMapped

Tags: memory, cuda, gpgpu, consistency, mapped-memory

Does anyone know of documentation on the memory consistency model guarantees for a memory region allocated with `cudaHostAlloc(..., cudaHostAllocMapped)`? For instance, when writes from the device become visible to reads from the host would be useful (could be after the kernel completes, at earliest possible time during kernel execution, etc).

Comment: You can force updates to be visible in a memory region allocated with cudaHostAlloc using [__threadfence_system()](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) on devices of cc 2.0 or greater.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writes from the device are guaranteed to be visible on the host (or on peer devices) after the performing thread has executed a [`__threadfence_system()`](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions) call (which is only available on compute capability 2.0 or higher).
They are also visible after the kernel has finished, i.e. after a `cudaDeviceSynchronize()` or after one of the other synchronization methods listed in the ["Explicit Synchronization" section of the Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-concurrent-execution) has been successfully completed.

Mapped memory should never be modified from the host while a kernel using it is or could be running, as CUDA currently does not provide any way of synchronization in that direction.